# Where should I connect my C wire on Goodman GMP075-3 Rev.B

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I am trying to install an ecobee4 to replace a digital battery powered thermostat.  I removed the existing thermostat and found that there was a spare blue wire that was wrapped around the others that runs to the furnace.  I tried connecting it in three different places and had no luck getting power to the smart thermostat.

In the picture below, you can see where I tried connecting the spare blue wire to both terminals 1 and 2, after reading another stackexchange answer for a similar furnace where people were saying that any 3 blue wires coming from the transformer could be used.  Unfortunately, neither worked to power the ecobee4.
[image: image 1]

It's hard to see, but in this other picture there is a white wire (from what I believe is the AC unit) going to the bigger blue wire, and I also tried twisting the little blue "C" wire in with the white and blue but this didn't work either.
[image]

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction for why this isn't working.  The previous thermostat had a jumper wire installed from the Rc to Rh terminals, *and* a red wire going into the Rh terminal (two wires in one thermostat terminal?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just twisting the wires together loosely, or using a proper splice (wirenut) to do the connecting? If it's the former, than that might be your problem right there...

Comment: Totally just twisting them together.  We just moved into this duplex and I believe that the landlord does not believe in hiring professionals.  I will try with a wirenut, but in theory it should still work when attached at locations 1 or 2 in the first picture, right?